# Perspective transformations for graphics

Tags: java, graphics, raytracing

I'm working on developing a ray tracer at the moment and I'm trying to work out the math behind some of the transformations I want to apply to the camera.

What I have for now, in code, is a viewpoint and a screen located a certain distance from it. I've managed to work out how to pan or tilt the camera but I'm not sure how to combine the two in one transformation.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to combine transformations is to first represent them as 4x4 matrices. Then a simple matrix multiplication produces a combination of two arbitrary transformations.